# Using Functions as Arguments to Function

Tags: functions, function-construction

I am trying to make a function like `Norm` but defined like so: `MyNorm[{x_,y_,z_}]=Sqrt[x^2+y^2+z^2]`. Mathematica assumes that x, y, and z are constants, and gives `MyNorm'[{x,y,z}]` to be `0` for any x, y, or z. This would be fine, except that my `x`, `y`, and `z` will be functions of `t`, and I would like `MyNorm'[{x,y,z}]` to be equal to $$\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \mathtt{MyNorm[\{}x(t),y(t),z(t)\mathtt{\}]}$$

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: `myNorm'[{x_, y_, z_}] := Dt[myNorm[{x, y, z}], t]`?

Comment: In the $\LaTeX$ example you have MyNorm with 3 arguments,  but in the code definition is has a single, vector argument. What is it now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`'` or `Derivative` has the following attributes:

```
Attributes[Derivative]
```

> {NHoldAll, ReadProtected}

Conspicuously absent is the `Protected` attribute. This means that, unlike many other system functions, downvalues for `Derivative` can be defined directly.

In this case you seem to want this definition (as suggested by wxffles in comments):

```
MyNorm'[{x_, y_, z_}] := Dt[MyNorm[{x, y, z}], t]
```

The total derivative `Dt` is needed here to explicitly indicate that all variables depend on t.

Show it works:

```
MyNorm'[{x, y, z}]
```

> (2 x Dt[x, t] + 2 y Dt[y, t] + 2 z Dt[z, t])/(2 Sqrt[
>    x^2 + y^2 + z^2])

If you clear the `ReadProtected` attribute you can see the definition is indeed assigned to `Derivative`:

```
ClearAttributes[Derivative, ReadProtected];
??Derivative
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Usually you would use `TagSet` or `TagSetDelayed` (`/: =` or `/: :=`) to associate this definition with `MyNorm` but in this case it would appear to deeply nested:

```
MyNorm /: MyNorm'[{x_, y_, z_}] := Dt[MyNorm[{x, y, z}], t]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

```
myNorm[{x_, y_, z_}] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2 + z^2];
Dt[myNorm[{x, y, z}], t]
```

Comment: While this does give the derivative of the norm function, when I attempt deriving myNorm[r[t]] where r[t] is a piecewise parametric function in three parts {x[t], y[t], z[t]}, it still returns an error message.

Comment: In addition, I need to have `MyNorm'[{x,y,z}]` evaluate to `Dt[myNorm[{x, y, z}], t]`.

Comment: @Ben7005 Edit your question and add all the relevant info

Comment: belisarius' answer strikes me as correct. If $x$, $y$, and $z$ are, in fact, functions (even in symbolic, as in `x[t]`), then this works fine. If they are not, then their derivatives should be zero.

Comment: Yes but as I said above I need to have MyNorm'[{x,y,z}] evaluate to Dt[myNorm[{x, y, z}], t]